# Is TIN a 2D or 3D mesh?

Tags: mesh

I have a TIN (Triangle Irregular Network) that was created in CAD software packages from something called DTM (essentially each point represents the height of the ground for that specific point).

The result looks like a 'blanket' of triangle, so not closed in any way. I think that's a non-boundary manifold triangle mesh but not sure. More unclear is if it is a 2D mesh (like a polygon is a 2D surface in a 3D Cartesian space even if not all vertexes are the same z). Can someone please explain what kind of geometry is a TIN?

Example (the blue triangles are the TIN):

[image: TIN]

Comment: Are you just asking about terminology? It would help to include some context for where you need to apply these definitions, as they might have subtly different meanings in different problem domains. In games, we could consider any mesh where only two faces meet at an edge as "2D" in terms of their local topology (like a navmesh), or "3D" in the sense that even if the mesh is flat like a billboarded particle or UI quad, we still send 3 coordinates' worth of information to the graphics card for projecting it onto the screen. Which term is more apt depends on what we're trying to do at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TINs can be either. From the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulated_irregular_network):

> Although usually associated with three-dimensional data (x, y, and z)
>   and topography, TINs are also useful for the description and analysis
>   of general horizontal (x and y) distributions and relationships.

A mesh does not need to be closed to be considered 3D, it simply needs to be described in 3 dimensions. In fact I'd say a majority of games have their terrain or large meshes "open" because the player will never see the bottom of a building or terrain, yet we don't consider those games to have 2D terrain.

The pictured mesh is most likely 3D, as it's one of the common uses cases depicting topography.